# How to match skin tones in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photo-editing

I took a picture but she has a really noticeable farmer's tan on her arms. Crazy Florida weather! How can I fix it in post production? I tried a color overlay but that didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Ok... you are cheating here... Xo) (Not true, cool Q&A)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really pretty easy to fix this type of skin color problem. I've got a video of this on my YouTube channel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9Q0M8FQiaU but here's a synopsis:

First you'll need to mask it - no getting around that. Then use a Selective Color adjustment layer. Now here's the secret sauce.

Grab the Eye Dropper, aka Color Sampler Tool, and select a point on the incorrect skin and on the correct skin. They'll both show up in your info panel.

Then you just adjust the Neutral in your Selective Color adjustment layer until your points match.

[image]